# retrieve last id inserted in object in a servlet

Tags: java, jpa, servlets

im doing an assessment for my college, my teacher gave me some initial code to copy and now im stucked with my own code. Basically this code create a new object to insert in the DB with an id. i need to catch the transaction id created in the object to send it to the next page. to review the transaction (marketplace portal). sorry for my english but its a little bit hard.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    int user_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("user_id"));
    int feed_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("feed_id"));
    Date now = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    //int transaction_done =0; MEANS NO TRANSACTION
    //int transaction_done =1; MEANS USER NTERESTED SEND APPLICATION TO REACH FEEDER 
    //int transaction_done =2; MEANS FEEDER DECLINE TRANSACTION
    //int transaction_done =3; MEANS TRANSACTION SUCCESSFULL, PROCEED WITH REVIEW
    int transaction_done =1;

    TransactionService objTransactionService = new TransactionService();        

    Transaction objTransaction = new Transaction(0, feed_id,user_id,now,transaction_done);

    if (objTransactionService.saveTransaction(objTransaction)) {
        HttpSession sesion=request.getSession();
        String done = "transaction in process! well done.";
        sesion.setAttribute("done", done);
        response.sendRedirect("chat.jsp?done=true");
    } else {
        HttpSession sesion=request.getSession();
        String done = "Error, try again.";
        sesion.setAttribute("done", done);
        response.sendRedirect("chat.jsp?done=false");
    }
}
```

hope you can help me.

Comment: Which API ( TransactionService) you are using for your persistence?

Comment: im using jpa ..